Html js Как при вводе в инпут, адреса страницы вк пользователя, вывести у себя на сайте его аву?
вводишь в поле ввода адрес страницы от вк жмешь кнопку и его ава высвечивается. можете помочь

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос. начните с декомпозиции своей комплексной хотелки, задавая составляющие её вопросы по отдельности.
